# Why was Boomer surprised of Daniel's existence?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004

In 4x17 "No Exit" Boomer learns about Daniel,

> the Cylon number seven, whom John made extinct.

She seems genuinely surprised at this, despite her often enough referred to as

> Eight by the other Cylons, although it was previously clear that only seven models were around the Cylon fleet.

She certainly wasn't that bad at counting as to be surprised of Daniel's existence, was she?

Comment: I forget, is she surprised by the existence or surprised by the extinction?

Comment: @Pam My memory claims by the mere existence, but I'll need to rewatch the scene. Surprise at John's role would of course make more sense...

Comment: @Pam Okay, I rewatched, but around 34:00 when it is discussed in detail, Boomer remains emotionless. Around 21:00 this is already alluded to, here Boomer sceptically eyes both of them, but I guess my memory of "surprise" is exaggerated...

Comment: I might have enough for an answer here but ... Daniel was a surprise because it was a surprise to everyone.  Remember that at the start, its heavily pressed to us both in and out of universe that there are 12 models.  Through the first couple of seasons, we are introduced to numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 8 - while 7 is left unnamed.  But then the "final five" concept came about (something the writers introduced late on in reaction to fans latching on to the missing cylons) and the numbering system broke down - the final five had to he 7, 9, 10, 11 and 12.  It didnt make sense.

Comment: So Daniel was tacked on near the end of the entire series just to make the numbering system sane - "hey, guess what, there were actually 13 models all along!  Hah, fooled ya!"

Comment: John boxing the entire line out of spite and keeping it secret was just a convenient explanation.